# Custom post archive in wordpress menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created an archive for custom post types in wordpress. Now I am trying to add the archive to my menu by adding a custom link to the menu.

When adding the link as http://example.com/posttype, it is changed to http://example.com/2015/07/posttype. How do I avoid this and get a correct link to my archive page in the menu?

Thanks!

Comment: So, your archive is a "page"?

Comment: I have used this code to add it:
`add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
 register_post_type( 'posstype',
  array(
   'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Posttype' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Posttype' )
   ),
  'public' => true,
  'has_archive' => true,
  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'posstype' )
  )
 );
}`

I can access it through http://example.com/posttype, since has_archive is enabled. I guess this makes it a page?

Comment: So basically, I need a way to add the http://example.com/posttype to my menu :-)

Comment: I have had success with this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-archive-links/. You could look in the code for that if you would rather not use a plugin. IIRC It is pretty lightweight.